# Run a gui application on cygwin

Tags: windows, opencv, cygwin, xserver

I am building application that is using OpenCV lib to show images. The application fails at the following line:

```
cv::namedWindow(....);
```

I am using cygwin on Windows 10, and using CLion IDE.

The executable is built successfully but when run it shows the following error:

```
(Display Image:10340): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I made sure `xinit` is installed and its dependencies using cygwin setup.
I've run the x server using a batch file with the following content:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe -p /usr/X11R6/bin XWin -listen tcp -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error
```

And I can see the 'X' icon in notification icons area, but still getting the error when I try to run the executable. I tried running it both from CLion and from cygwin console but same result.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Have you defined DISPLAY ? Does the application work if you run it from a Xterm ?

Comment: I tried to run it form XTerm and yes it is running, it took me time to find XTerm. Now what is the way to make it run and debug from CLion?

Comment: You could try to target WSL instead. While not a supported scenario, there have been reports, that users managed to set up an XServer.

Comment: There is an app "GWSL" in MS Store that will automatically set up x server for you and merge it with windows native desktop manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a program that need access to a X Server you need:

> 1) a running X Server
>    2) the variable DISPLAY defined

If you check from Xterm you will have:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

So your program can run as DISPLAY is defined and the X server is found.

Comment: Thanks, the value that worked for me was `:0`. I wonder though why this is not mentioned any where I looked. Cheers

Comment: http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-xserver-nolisten-tcp-default and  http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#display-and-screen